# Where does tmux keep logs on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, crash, tmux, tmuxinator

tmux has been crashing a lot lately, and I'm not sure why.  I want to look into it further, but I don't know where I can find any kind of logs, or error messages.  So far, my googling for "tmux log location" and the like has come up empty.

I'm running OS X, and installed tmux via Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

The manual page needs some work (you may not see the feature at first).  But starting from the source code (referring to version 2.1 in `tty.c`) you may see

```
    if (debug_level > 3) {
            xsnprintf(out, sizeof out, "tmux-out-%ld.log", (long) getpid());
            fd = open(out, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644);
            if (fd != -1 && fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) == -1)
                    fatal("fcntl failed");
            tty->log_fd = fd;
    }
```

The `-v` flag sets the `debug_level` value; repeating it increases the value.  Back to the manual page:

> **`-v`**
>   Request verbose logging. This option may be specified multiple times for increasing verbosity. Log messages will be saved into ***tmux-client-PID.log*** and ***tmux-server-PID.log*** files in the *current directory*, where PID is the PID of the server or client process.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to specify some directory (other than the current directory) where the log files should be written to? Is there an environment variable or something that we can specify to change where the logs are written to?